# JavaFX: Focus Request via TCP/IP in Multi Process Applications

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to set the focus to a JavaFX TextField from multiple applications.

The application should be a user management for multiple applications. From each application I want to be able to request the login dialog to be shown and active, so the user can just enter username and password without any further click. Since not all applications are Java based I realized the login request via TCP/IP.

The focus request seems to work for the textfield. The textfield appears as if it has the focus, but I do not get the focus to the application. Any suggestions?

Attached are two sample applications to demonstrate the behaviour. First start the sample login dialog, then the sample external apllication. A click on the login-Button changes the focus in the login dialog, but I can not enter text in the TextFields without clicking on the sample login dialog.

Sample Login Dialog

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FocusApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        TextField userField = new TextField();
        PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();

        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("User"), userField, new Label("Password"), passwordField);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Request Focus");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox, 400, 300));

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
                    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

                    Scanner in = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());

                    while (true) {
                        String command = in.nextLine();
                        if ("login".equals(command)) {
                            System.out.println("login recieved");
                            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    primaryStage.show();
                                    primaryStage.toFront();
                                    primaryStage.requestFocus();
                                    if (userField.isFocused()) {
                                        passwordField.requestFocus();
                                    } else {
                                        userField.requestFocus();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Sample External Application

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TriggerFocusApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Socket server = new Socket("localhost",  1234);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);

        Button triggerButton = new Button("Login");
        triggerButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                out.println("login");
            }
        });

        HBox hbox = new HBox(5);
        hbox.getChildren().add(triggerButton);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Trigger Focus Request");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hbox, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```